How to get an Apps Script script to wait for data to finalize on a sheet before executing?
I have a script which takes information from a Google Sheet which collates data from multiple different sources then sends an email with the relevant data.
However, due to the numerous dynamic functions used such as Importrange, the sheet will sometimes need to recalculate and need some additional attempts to load.
Is there a way to allow a script to account for this and execute after these recalculation attempts are finished?
I have already attempted to use SpreadsheetApp.flush and Utilities.sleep after the initial passing of the spreadsheet name e.g:
var wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dataSheet = wb.getSheetByName("Test Mailsheet");
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
Utilities.sleep(50000);

To no avail. Is there any other method to force a sheet to wait before grabbing the data before executing?

you could perhaps bind all your lazy formulae to some simple boolean statement and fire script only if output TRUE. nothing fancy, say you have  IMPORTRANGE in A1 and GOOGLEFINANCE in D1. while they load, usually first cell outputs error or loading msg while the last expected to be populated cell is empty, so =(A1<>"")*(D10<>"") output will be either TRUE or FALSE/ERROR

That makes sense, will probably have to fiddle with the script trigger a little, but that should work in theory. Will report back with my results
